# How to restrict a user's access for accounts they do not own

Tags: security, professional-edition, roles, record-access-level

I have a roles hierarchy like in the image attached. One Sales Manager and UNDER this role, two other roles: Sales_Europe and Sales_US.
Assigned to these two roles, i have two users: user_a (Role: Sales_US) and user_b (Role: Sales_EU).
THE OWD is set on PRIVATE for all objects and the Grant Access Using Hierarchy set on ON to all.

I do have Professional License.

I would like that Sales_EU does NOT see the accounts they do NOT own. 
(Unfortunatelly the user_a sees the contacts they do not own.)

The question: HOW can I enforce this security model?
TIA

Ovidiu[image: Sales Force Security Config - issue]

Comment: Do you have any permissions on the profile of user-b or user-a to see or modify all records?

Comment: As I do have Professional License, I do not have access to such kind of settings on user level... (I do not see/got access the Profiles menu item). My users are created on built-in Standard Profile...

Comment: Reasons a user might be able to see a particular record 1) Permissions - view all data 2)Record Ownership 3) OWD - Read Only or Read/Write 4) Roles - above the owner 5) Sharing - Sharing rules or Manual Sharing. In your case 2,3&4 are not applicable what if someone is manually sharing or it could be the reason 1) View all permission on Contact object for their profiles.

Comment: @OvidiuDiaconu Does the user_a own any cases related to the contacts they can view currently? This may be due to implicit sharing.

Comment: @Bennie: no, they don't. But, based on the feedback I got from Mihai Neagoe, asking me to post the "Why?" screenshot, i found the (two) causes of that security issue: 1) somewhere, upper in the hierarchy, there was a role, who through an "Account sharing rule" was grating everybody below access to all accounts. 2) as well, there was an contact (rule) that was sharing his accounts with that role the user_a belongs...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on your schema you need to implement two sharing rules on Account and on other object you need to segregate the data.

We have role Euro and role US. The first sharing rule you create will say, any records created by role Euro give read/write access to role Euro. The second one will be for the US role and it will be the same as the first one.

[image: sharing]

Click on Expand List button which will point you to a list with all the reasons which user can what record and the reason.

[image: Expand List]

Let me know if it solved your problem.

Comment: I will give a try on your solution - and I will let you know afterwards. Therefore a Thank you in advance. Still, why they do see each other's records, if the OWD says everything should be Private?

Comment: It might be to do with the option Grant Access Using Hierarchy set to On and might give you some standard functionality that you might not desire. Read more here https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_controlling_access_using_hierarchies.htm&language=en_US and see if it does what you think it does.

Comment: I did as instructed. But same (unwilling) behavior. I created an "account sharing rule" with the next settings: Account: Owned by members of Role: SALES_US, Share with: Role: SALES_US, Default account...:  Read/Write, Contact access: R/W, all of them with R/W. And my user_a still have access to accounts not owned... :-(

Comment: Additional tests I did, revealed the next behavior: accounts created by user_a are not visible by user_b and vice-versa. But accounts created (owner) by other users, upper or in parallel hierarchies are visible in both user_a and user_b accounts...

Comment: Have you created both of the rules before testing? I recommend reviewing the other sharing rules, once you create a record you will have a button next to the other standard buttons called Sharing and then further more you can click on expand list. You can try and find out more and why that record is shared by pressing it. Updated my answer.

Comment: @MihaiNeagoe - How will this help the problem. This solution shares records with other users in the US role that may NOT be above them in the hierarchy....Did I miss the part where the OP asked to share accounts with all users in the same role?

Comment: @Eric, from what I understood from the problem, he wants a segregation of data between the two roles, Sales EU and Sales US on accounts. What I suggested is to create the sharing rules to ensure that, then he replied that he tested my solution and couldn't get the desired outcome. I advised him to look further into the other sharing rules and potentially review them, they might cause unexpected behavior. By using the sharing button and the expand list button he can drill down and understand the rules.

Comment: I added in my answer above the screenshot with the "WHY" sharing record. But, being new in salesforce, I can't really understand the info I get there... Anyone willing to help me with that? TIA

Comment: @MihaiNeagoe - Whiteboard shows object model Private and NO Sharing Rules

Comment: @Eric, I'm not really sure what you mean by the comment. Anyways, Ovidiu the reason you have the Private OWD on account object but the role still sees the other role's data is due to your other sharing rule. As you can see in the Why table the Sales US might be in one of the other sharing rules. I recommend reviewing them before creating other rules.

Comment: @MihaiNeagoe: thanks for your tips. It helped me identifying and fixing the problems i had.

Answer (score 0):

These are my overall settings.

[image: Role Hierarchy] 
[image: Company OWD]
[image: Account Sharing Rules]
[image: Role definition]

Add the WHY screenshot. How do I "read" this information? Thanks!
[image: Explanation of access]